# Cascade GPU detectMultiScale confidence level in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I have a working program, in OpenCV 3.0, using a cascade classifier with a custom XML file.

I want to speed it up, so I changed it for a GPU method.
Here is the working program (CPU method):

```
// image_src (cv::Mat) is the source image, captured from webcam
cv::CascadeClassifier cascade;  
cv::Mat image_src_gray;
vector<cv::Rect> foundObjects;
vector<int> numDetect;

cv::cvtColor( image_src, image_src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

cascade.detectMultiScale(
    image_src_gray,
    foundObjects, // return: objects vector
    numDetect, // return: confidence vector
    1.1,
    4, // neighbors
    0|cv::CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, // flags
    cv::Size(40,40), // minSize
    image_src.size() // maxSize
);
```

In this way, I am able to know the confidence of each detected object, and to filter out the bad results, with numDetect vector. I use one of the three forms of [detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale).

With the GPU program, the function detectMultiScale seems to NOT have the ability to return the confidence results.
Here is the GPU program:

```
// image_src (cv::Mat) is the source image, captured from webcam
cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> cascade_gpu;
cv::cuda::GpuMat image_src_gpu, image_src_gray_gpu;
vector<cv::Rect> foundObjects;
vector<int> numDetect;

image_src_gpu.upload(image_src);
cv::cuda::cvtColor( image_src_gpu, image_src_gray_gpu, CV_BGR2GRAY );

cascade_gpu->setFindLargestObject(true);
cascade_gpu->setScaleFactor(1.1);
cascade_gpu->setMinNeighbors(4);
cascade_gpu->setMinObjectSize(cv::Size(40,40));
cascade_gpu->setMaxObjectSize(image_src.size());

cv::cuda::GpuMat foundObjects_gpu;

cascade_gpu->detectMultiScale(
    image_src_gray_gpu,
    foundObjects_gpu
    );
cascade_gpu->convert( foundObjects_gpu, foundObjects );
```

This is working fine, but the results can't be filtered according to the confidence level. Cuda [detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d9/d80/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#a182656b878046eb3f0e9c0f0ee327f08) have only one form, without the confidence levels return.

How can I know the confidence level of each detected object?

My setting: Ubuntu 14.04.1, kernel 3.19.0-25, openCV 3.0, cuda 7.5.
Hardware: i7-2600K - PNY/nVidia Quadro 4000.